Laravel 11 redirectifauthenticated middleware problem for custom guard
I have two auth guards: 'web' (default) and 'admin', both of which are from the user's model. The issue is that when I log in as an 'admin' guard, I can still access the '/login' or '/registration' or any page that is protected by the guest middleware.
I'm using Laravel UI auth. Please tell me if I need to do something differently or if Laravel has become so poor that it can handle its own custom guard feature.
Config/auth.php
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],


'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => env('AUTH_MODEL', App\Models\User::class),
        ],


        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => env('AUTH_MODEL', App\Models\User::class),
        ],
    ],

Routes
Route::middleware('guest')->group(function () {
    Volt::route('register', 'pages.auth.register')
        ->name('register');

    Volt::route('login', 'pages.auth.login')
        ->name('login');

    Volt::route('forgot-password', 'pages.auth.forgot-password')
        ->name('password.request');

    Volt::route('reset-password/{token}', 'pages.auth.reset-password')
        ->name('password.reset');
});

LoginController.php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function login(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'email' => ['required', 'email'],
            'password' => ['required'],
        ]);
        
        $credentials['active'] = 1;

        $guard = $this->getGuard($credentials);

        if (Auth::guard($guard)->attempt($credentials)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();

            if ($guard === 'admin') {
                return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
            } else {
                return redirect()->intended('profile');
            }
        }
 
        return back()->withErrors([
            'email' => 'Wrong credentials',
        ])->onlyInput('email');
    }

    protected function getGuard(array $credentials)
    {
        if (isset($credentials['email'])) {
            $user = User::where('email', $credentials['email'])->first();
            if ($user && $user->admin) {
                return 'admin';
            }
        }

        return 'web';
    }

    public function logout(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        Auth::logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();
        $request->session()->regenerateToken();
     
        return redirect('/login');
    }
}

As you can see in my code above, I don't see what seems to be the issue.

your default guard is web so the guest middleware is using the web middleware, and since you are not authenticated to the web guard you are a guest ... also, why would you have 2 guards that are using the same Model?

Well I want to keep one table user where I have a column admin which I set 1 to make any user as admin, so that's why I'm using same model , but is there a way to edit the guest middleware in laravel 11 to make admin guard consider not as guest

@Faraz Have you tried Route::middleware('guest:admin')?

@Faraz the reason you have provided still makes no sense as to why you would need two auth guards. If you want to protect admin route from non admin users, make a middleware that checks just that

@krisgjika basically i don't have to use any other middleware but just auth:admin as simple as that

@ArunAS yes already tried but not working

@Faraz please post your RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware
